# java: use existing object or create a new one?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

What is better:

This

```
public Move(moveString) {
    ArrayList<Square> moveSquares = splitToSquares(moveString.toLowerCase());
    this.from = new Square(moveSquares.get(0));
    this.to = new Square(moveSquares.get(1));
}
```

or this:

```
public Move(moveString) {
    ArrayList<Square> moveSquares = splitToSquares(moveString.toLowerCase());
    this.from = moveSquares.get(0);
    this.to = moveSquares.get(1);
}
```

In the first, I use the information from the move objects to create a new one.
In the second, I directly use the object.

It doesn't make much difference for my program now, but I am wondering if Java needs to keep the complete ArrayList because I referenced them. If that is a huge list, it would be better to just copy the two objects I need and let the rest be collected by the GC, wouldn't it?

Or is the GC intelligent enough to do that himself? Then the first method would make unnecessary copies of the objects. Not a big deal in this case, but in another there may be hundreds or thousands such objects.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, the `ArrayList` will not be referenced once you exit the `Move()` method.  It does not matter that you reference elements *within* the list.  If the list itself is unreachable, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

The two referenced elements will remain alive as long they are referenced by another live object.  In your second example, those two elements will be reachable at least as long as your `Move` object is reachable.  But if there are *other* elements in the list, and they are not referenced outside of the list, then *those* elements will be eligible for garbage collection when the list goes out of scope.

Comment: So basically, the first method works just fine and has no undesirable side effects in terms of wasted memory?

Comment: Both work fine.  The second is probably preferable unless you have other reasons for duplicating the squares.

Answer (score 2):

Your list `moveSquares` becomes unreachable as soon as the `Move` constructor ends (this is a reasonable assumption, although it ultimately depends on what exactly the `splitToSquares` method does).

In additon to that, the fact that one item of the list is still reachable has nothing to do with the reachability of the list itself, or of any other list item. They will all become unreachable, thus collectible.

Comment: Should have said that right away: splitToSquares creates a new ArrayList, fills it with objects of class Square, and returns that list.

Comment: Marko, by "They will all become unreachable" do you mean all other list items (the ones that are not referenced)?

Comment: Yes, all other items.